# How do I use elm-monocle with a sum type?

Tags: elm, lenses

How do I write a lens that accesses a field inside a record, which is itself inside a sum type?

I have a model like this:

```
type alias Coords =
  { x : Maybe String
  , y : Maybe String
  }

type alias Foo =
  { coords : Maybe Coords
  }

type alias Bar =
  { coords : Maybe Coords
  }

type Thing = FooThing Foo | BarThing Bar

type alias Model =
  { thing : Maybe Thing
  }
```

I know that I can access the `Thing` inside the `Model` with

```
thingLens : Optional Model Thing
thingLens = Optional .thing (\b a -> { a | thing = Just b })
```

…and I believe I can get the `x` from a `Foo` with

```
xFromFoo : Optional Thing String
xFromFoo = Optional .x (\b a -> { a | x = b })
```

…but how do I compose these? I want to go from the `Model` to the `x` inside the `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I came up with this, which works:

```
thingL : Optional Model Thing
thingL = Optional .thing (\b a -> { a | thing = Just b })

thingFooCoordsL : Optional Thing Coords
thingFooCoordsL =
  let get a = case a of
        FooThing f -> f.coords
        _ -> Nothing
      set val thing = case thing of
        FooThing f ->
          FooThing { f | coords = Just val }
        a -> a
   in Optional get set

coordsXL : Optional Coords String
coordsXL = Optional .x (\b a -> { a | x = Just b })

fooThingCoordsXL : Optional Model Title
fooThingCoordsXL = thingL
  |> Monocle.Compose.optionalWithOptional thingFooCoordsL
  |> Monocle.Compose.optionalWithOptional coordsXL
```

Basically you need a lens which wraps and unwraps the sum types, and you need a different lens for each constructor of the sum type you wish to access.